# Running ASP.NET Core app from Amazon Linux 2 on Docker - Globalization

Tags: docker, .net-core, rhel, icu, amazon-linux

I have my ASP.NET Core app running beautifully (more or less) on `microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-jessie`. Now I want to try to get it to deploy to `amazonlinux:2`.

So far, the biggest hurdle has been `libicu`. I tried setting Globalization to Invariant, but this caused weird failures in, e.g., mySQL database calls.

Here's the relevant step from my Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -L --http1.1 http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/57.1/icu4c-57_1-RHEL6-x64.tgz --output icu.tgz \
    && tar -xf icu.tgz -C / \
    && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib \
    && rm icu.tgz
```

(SourceForge was down while I was trying to work on this yesterday, which didn't improve matters.)

In any case, I still get the message of doom from .NET Core:

> FailFast: Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.

Any suggestions how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I revisited this yesterday. I don't know if it's because the base .tar of the Amazon Linux image has been updated, or because I was doing something wrong last time, but I installed the following packages using yum and all was well:

- libunwind
- libicu
- dotnet-hosting-2.0.5

Note that for the dotnet package I needed first to set up Microsoft's package repository for yum, i.e.

```
rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
```

and copying the following file to /etc/yum.repos.d/dotnetdev.repo :

```
[packages-microsoft-com-prod] 
name=packages-microsoft-com-prod 
baseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/microsoft-rhel7.3-prod 
enabled=1 
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
```

(see [Microsoft's instructions for CentOS and other Linux distros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x#install-net-core-for-centos-71-64-bit--oracle-linux-71-64-bit))